# Qt QGraphicsDropShadowEffect is not showing

Tags: python, qt, qt4, pyqt, pyside

I am creating a custom widget `my_widget` inheriting from `QWidget`.

Here, I have a label to which I would like to apply `QGraphicsDropShadowEffect` however it does not seem to be working since I don't see any shadows.

My code is in Python and it's:

```
eff = QGraphicsDropShadowEffect()
self.my_widget_label.setGraphicsEffect(eff)
```

I tried various alterations to this code to no avail.

After doing a through search on Google, I came across many similar questions without answers.

What might be the cause? How can I get the shadow?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

See if this works for you:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
#-*- coding:utf-8 -*-

import sip
sip.setapi('QString', 2)
sip.setapi('QVariant', 2)

from PyQt4.QtCore import *
from PyQt4.QtGui import *

class testShadow(QWidget):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(testShadow, self).__init__(parent)

        self.resize(94, 35)
        self.verticalLayout = QVBoxLayout(self)
        self.verticalLayout.setObjectName("verticalLayout")
        self.label = QLabel(self)
        self.label.setText("Text Label")

        self.shadow = QGraphicsDropShadowEffect(self)
        self.shadow.setBlurRadius(5)
        self.label.setGraphicsEffect(self.shadow)

        self.verticalLayout.addWidget(self.label)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    import  sys

    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    main = testShadow()
    main.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

[image]

Comment: Hello @X.Jacobs! Unfortunately, it does not work and it crashes like @jdi mention earlier. I think I need to subclass QLabel and use its paintEvent to draw the label with shadow effect. Could you help me with that please? I have spent the past hour trying to do that but I am not sure how to re-implement entire paintEvent of a QLabel to draw the label itself. Thank you!

Comment: You can always have a look at the Qt sources themselves for inspiration.

Comment: @X.Jacobs, I did run the code, of course. I would not want to waste anybody's time. I am on a Mac and using PySide. It does not work. I am getting the following error: QPainter::begin: Widget painting can only begin as a result of a paintEvent
QPainter::translate: Painter not active
Segmentation fault: 11

Answer (score 4):

Works for me in C++. I did the following in a `QDialog` containing a `QLabel` object named `titleLabel`. I'm using Qt 4.8.4 on a Windows XP computer.

```
QGraphicsDropShadowEffect* eff = new QGraphicsDropShadowEffect(this);
eff->setBlurRadius(5);
titleLabel->setGraphicsEffect(eff);
```

Comment: Hi @DanielHadberg. Thank you very much for checking it out for me. I am currently on a Mac. Perhaps then *that* might be the issue. Thanks again!

Comment: Hope you'll find a solution that works. Could it be Python related? Make sure the effect object doesn't get destroyed somehow. I assume it's allocated on the heap so it shouldn't.

Comment: Dear @DanielHedberg, I tried and tried but gave up on this. I am creating a second label to give some sort of "depth". I think it's either Mac or Python abstraction issues of Qt libraries. Thanks a lot though!

Answer (score 2):

I have only every tried to use this (and used it successfully) in `QGraphicsScene` situations. This works for me, while trying to set it on a normal `QWidget` actually crashes the entire application:

```
from PyQt4 import QtGui

class Graphics(QtGui.QWidget):
    def __init__(self):
        super(Graphics, self).__init__()

        layout = QtGui.QVBoxLayout(self)
        layout.setMargin(0)

        shad = QtGui.QGraphicsDropShadowEffect(self)
        shad.setBlurRadius(5)

        self.scene = QtGui.QGraphicsScene(self)
        self.view = QtGui.QGraphicsView(self)
        self.view.setScene(self.scene)
        text = self.scene.addText("Drop Shadow!")
        text.setGraphicsEffect(shad)

        layout.addWidget(self.view)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = QtGui.QApplication([])
    main = Graphics()
    main.show()
    main.raise_()
    app.exec_()
```

Comment: I was missing the 'setGraphicsEffect' call. Thanks!