# QPushButton becomes invisible when adding QGraphicsDropShadow effect if parent widget has an effect also

Tags: python, python-3.x, pyqt, qt5, pyqt5

I'm using QFrame to make 'cards' with drop shadows using QGraphicsDropShadowEffect.  The issue I'm having, is if I add a button to the card, then add a drop shadow to the button, the button is invisible but still clickable.  If I remove the drop shadow from the card, it shows the button fine, or if I remove the shadow from the button, it's visible.  It seems I can't have drop shadows on both the card and the button.

My classes:

```
class Card(QFrame):
    """ """
    def __init__(self, title='Card Title', cls_layout=QVBoxLayout,
                 vsizing=QSizePolicy.Preferred, hsizing=QSizePolicy.Preferred,
                 has_shadow=False, subtitle='', parent=None):
        super().__init__(parent)

        self.has_shadow = has_shadow
        self.setStyleSheet('QFrame { border-radius: 2px; background: white;}')
        self._layout = QVBoxLayout(self)
        self._layout.setAlignment(Qt.AlignTop)
        self._lblTitle = QLabel(title)
        self._lblTitle.setFont(make_font(pt=12, b=True))
        self._lblSubtitle = QLabel()
        self._lblSubtitle.setIndent(4)
        self._layout.addWidget(self._lblTitle)
        self._layout.addWidget(self._lblSubtitle)
        self._layout.addSpacing(4)
        #self.subtitle = subtitle # property not used for example
        self.enabled = True

        self.layout = cls_layout()  # where content is added
        self._layout.addLayout(self.layout)
        self.setSizePolicy(hsizing, vsizing)

    @property
    def enabled(self):
        return self.isEnabled()

    @enabled.setter
    def enabled(self, state):
        if state and self.has_shadow:
            effect = QGraphicsDropShadowEffect(self)
            effect.setOffset(1, 2)
            effect.setBlurRadius(4)
            self.setGraphicsEffect(effect)
        else:
            self.setGraphicsEffect(None)

        self.setEnabled(state)

class PushButton(QPushButton):
    def __init__(self, text, width=75, height=30, parent=None):
        super().__init__(text, parent)
        self.setFixedWidth(width)
        self.setFixedHeight(height)
        self.enabled = True

    @property
    def enabled(self):
        return self.isEnabled()

    @enabled.setter
    def enabled(self, state):
        self.setGraphicsEffect(None)
        if state:
            self.effect = QGraphicsDropShadowEffect(self)
            self.effect.setOffset(1, 2)
            self.effect.setBlurRadius(4)
            self.setGraphicsEffect(self.effect)

        self.setEnabled(state)
```

This is an example of how I'm using them:

```
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QApplication, QMainWindow, QWidget, QVBoxLayout
import sys


if __name__ == '__main__':

    app = QApplication([])

    window = QMainWindow()
    widget = QWidget()
    layout = QVBoxLayout(widget)
    window.setCentralWidget(widget)

    card = Card(has_shadow=True)
    btn = PushButton('Test Button')
    btn.clicked.connect(print)
    card.layout.addWidget(btn)
    btn.enabled = False  # Button Visible
    # btn.enabled = True   # Button Invisible, but still click-able

    layout.addWidget(card)

    window.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

I tried ditching the drop shadow on the card and setting the QFrame to StyledPanel with Raised shadow, but I can't get them to show up, even if I remove the css from it. I'm using Windows 7 with Anaconda 4.4 if that makes a difference.  I'm assuming I'm either using the graphics effect wrong or doing something else incorrectly, but I haven't been able to find any other posts with a similar issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up using [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14016769/8325193) method and changing my button class to:

```
class Button(QWidget):
    clicked = pyqtSignal()

    def __init__(self, text, w=75, h=50, parent=None):
        super().__init__(parent)
        layout = QVBoxLayout(self)
        layout.setContentsMargins(QMargins(0, 0, 0, 0))
        self.setFixedSize(w + 5, h + 6)
        self.setSizePolicy(QSizePolicy.Fixed, QSizePolicy.Fixed)

        self.scene = QtWidgets.QGraphicsScene(self)
        self.view = QtWidgets.QGraphicsView(self)
        self.view.setScene(self.scene)
        self._btn = QPushButton(text)
        self._btn.setFixedSize(w, h)
        self._btn.setAttribute(Qt.WA_TranslucentBackground)
        self._btn.setStyleSheet(gui.css.button_css())
        self._btn.clicked.connect(self.click)
        self.btn = self.scene.addWidget(self._btn)
        self.enabled = True

        layout.addWidget(self.view)

    @property
    def enabled(self):
        return self._btn.isEnabled()

    @enabled.setter
    def enabled(self, state):
        self._btn.setEnabled(state)

        if state:
            shadow = QGraphicsDropShadowEffect(self)
            shadow.setOffset(1, 2)
            shadow.setBlurRadius(4)
            self.btn.setGraphicsEffect(shadow)
        else:
            self.btn.setGraphicsEffect(None)

    def click(self):
        self.clicked.emit()
```